# socket never got connected

Tags: java, sockets, ip-address, port-number

**I was trying to use the socket to connect the server but when I put the parameter to be localhost, it works. but when I put my ip address in there it never works, So I don't know what was wrong, the ip address I got was from http://whatismyipaddress.com**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

    public static void main( String [] arg ) throws Exception
    {
        Socket      socket;
        BufferedReader  stdIn;
        BufferedReader  fromServer;
        PrintWriter toServer;
        String      s;
        String      result;

        socket = new Socket( "96.63.208.240", 5000 );
        stdIn = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
        fromServer = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream() ) );
        toServer = new PrintWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( socket.getOutputStream() ), true );
        while ( (s = stdIn.readLine()) != null )
        {
            toServer.println( s );
            result = fromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println( "reverse: " + result );
        }
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

**The sever side**

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    public static void main( String [] arg ) throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket    serverSocket = new ServerSocket( 5000, 10 );
        Socket      socket;

        serverSocket.setReuseAddress( true );
        while ( (socket = serverSocket.accept()) != null )
        {
            System.out.println( "Accepted an incoming connection" );
            new SessionThread( socket ).start();
        }
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is on a home type network - have you enabled port forwarding on your router for port 5000?

Comment: sorry do you know how to do that?

Comment: If you log in to your router there should be a port forwarding section and route the traffic from port 5000 to your local IP.

Answer (score 1):

You porbably forgot to set port forwarding, because you specified global IP router by default does not know to which device inside local network should it send to (devices in local network have local ip which you can find with cmd: `ipconfig`). So you manualy tell router to send every packet it come to port 5000 from internet to direct it to device with IP eg. 192.168.1.5

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the request flow to solve your problem.
With **localhost** you are making a request directly to your computer, he doesn't event get out to the network.
When you put your **external IP** (that you have found through whatismyipaddress.com) the request will exit your computer and ask your router where is the machine with that IP. That said, the request flow will be:

1. Your computer
2. Your router
3. ISP DNS
4. Your router again (because your ISP knows your IP)
5. Your computer again

But in this last step there's is a problem. Due to security reasons your router will block any external request to access your private network. There's is the part where you must configure your router port forwarding (as mentioned before) and tell him that any request from outside of your private network must be redirected to your local IP, this way will work. To configure port forwarding just access your router through your browser (like 192.168.1.1), login and go to port forwarding or something similar. The configuration steps should be very explicit.
But don't forget, your local and event external IP can change, so if it stop work again check if the IP's remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: Maybe more useful for you.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    // arguments supply message and hostname of destination
    Socket s = null;
        try{
            int serverPort = 7896;
        s = new Socket(args[1], serverPort);    
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream( s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out =
            new DataOutputStream( s.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF(args[0]);          // UTF is a string encoding see Sn 4.3
        String data = in.readUTF();       
        System.out.println("Received: "+ data) ;      
            }catch (UnknownHostException e){
            System.out.println("Sock:"+e.getMessage()); 
        }catch (EOFException e){System.out.println("EOF:"+e.getMessage());
            }catch (IOException e){System.out.println("IO:"+e.getMessage());}

        if (s != null)
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("close:" + e.getMessage());
            }
    }
}
```

And for server side use this one.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            int serverPort = 7896;
            ServerSocket listenSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = listenSocket.accept();
                Connection c = new Connection(clientSocket);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Listen :" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class Connection extends Thread {
    DataInputStream in;
    DataOutputStream out;
    Socket clientSocket;

    public Connection(Socket aClientSocket) {
        try {
            clientSocket = aClientSocket;
            in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            this.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try { // an echo server
            String data = in.readUTF();
            out.writeUTF(data);
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            System.out.println("EOF:" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO:" + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            /* close failed */}
    }
}
```